# How do I write REG_MULTI_SZ values to the Registry?

Tags: c++, winapi, registry

I'm trying to write a REG_MULTI_SZ value to the Windows Registry using C++. Where I'm stuck is on converting the c-strings that I have to MULTI_SZ format. Is there a convenient way to do this?

Comment: Relevant reading: ["What is the format of a double-null-terminated string with no strings?"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2009/10/08/9904646.aspx)

Comment: The format expected here is NOT the same as in the article linked above. No final null character is needed to terminate the list. Doing so will in fact add an empty string to the list of values, which may be undesired.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to do it yourself. Given

```
char ** strings; // array of strings
int N; // number of strings
```

you count the length of the multi_sz

```
int len=1;
for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
  len += strlen(strings[i])+1;
```

and fill it

```
char* multi_sz = malloc(len), ptr=multi_sz;
memset(multi_sz, 0, len);
for(int i=0; i<N; i++) {
  strcpy(ptr, strings[i]);
  ptr += strlen(strings[i])+1;
}
```

Comment: I wish there was a more convenient interface. Seems error prone.

Comment: The question is about C++, not C

Answer (score 2):

Here's a C++0x alternative.

```
static const std::string vals [] = 
{
    "a", "bb", "ccc"
};
static const size_t num_vals = sizeof(vals)/sizeof(vals[0]);
std::string reg_out = std::accumulate(&vals[0], &vals[num_vals], std::string(), [](std::string& so_far, const std::string& cur) -> std::string
{
    so_far += cur;
    so_far += '\0';
    return so_far;
});
reg_out += '\0';
reg_out.size();

RegSetValueEx(...,...,...,REG_MULTI_SZ, rerinterpret_cast<const BYTE*>(&reg_out[0]), reg_out.size());
```

Comment: Those are some fancy lambdas. I don't think Visual Studio 2008 (the version I'm using for this project) has support for the new C++ features though. :(

Comment: @nathan:  VS 2008 does not, but I wrote the above using VS 2010.  Isn't it time to move up anyway? :)

Comment: I do have VS 2010, but this particular project is a Smart Device project targeted for WinCE.

Answer (score 0):

If all values are constants, then you may want to use a string literal, rather than unnecessary composing the strings.

If you construct a C++ string from a string literal, then the first null character will terminate it:

```
string s("aaa\0bbb");  // constructs the string "aaa"
```

However, a C++ string may contain null characters and can be constructed from a string literal containing null characters as follows:

```
const char sz[] = "aaa\0bbb";
string szs(sz, sizeof(sz) / sizeof(char));  // constructs the string "aaa\0bbb"
```

Then you can simply do:

```
RegSetValueEx(...,...,...,REG_MULTI_SZ, rerinterpret_cast<const BYTE*>(&szs[0]), szs.size());
```

Note that, unlike what is suggested in other answers, there is **no** need for two null characters at the end of the value (one for terminating the last string and one for terminating the list). Doing so will in fact add an empty string to the list of values, which may be undesired. In this example, the second string (and the entire list) is terminated by the null character, which is automatically added at the end of the C++ string.